# Rewriting Java native methods using ASM

Tags: java, java-native-interface, metaprogramming, sandbox, bytecode

I'm trying to do this by re-writing the bytecode of the class using [ASM 4.0](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) to replace all the `native` methods with non-`native` stubs.

So far I have this:

```
class ClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor {

    public ClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM4, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String base, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        return cv.visitMethod(access & ~Opcodes.ACC_NATIVE, base, desc, signature, exceptions);
    }

}
```

which is executed by

```
private static byte[] instrument(byte[] originalBytes, ClassLoader loader) {
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    ClassAdapter adapter = new ClassAdapter(cw);

    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalBytes);
    cr.accept(adapter, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);

    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

Which seems simple enough: I strip the `ACC_NATIVE` off of the method in `visitMethod()` and leave everything else unchanged. However, when I do this to `java.lang.Object`, it dies with a

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

The StackOverflow happens at *instrumentation* time, not at *runtime*, which I think is rather unusual. However, if I remove the `& ~Opcodes.ACC_NATIVE` modifier, `java.lang.Object` gets rewritten (in this case unchanged) and executes perfectly.

Clearly I am not doing something right, and replacing the `native` method with a non-`native` method isn't quite as simple as stripping off the `native` modifier on the method, but I have no idea where to start. The [ASM Docs](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) don't talk about working with `native` methods at all. Does anyone with experience working with ASM know what I need to do to get the `native` method re-writing to work?

### EDIT

Sorry, that short, useless message was what `e.printStackTrace()` was giving me, but using `e.getStackTrace()` I managed to get something useful:

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:332)
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1124)
java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.add(Collections.java:3903)
sandbox.classloader.MyClassLoader.instrument(Unknown Source)
sandbox.classloader.MyClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
sandbox.classloader.MyClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
sandbox.classloader.MyClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sandbox.Tester.main(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

So it seems to me that the error was in fact happening at execution time (e.g. I was mistaken in thinking it was at instrumentation time) and is the result of calling `hashCode()`. As it so happens, `hashCode()` one of the native methods which I (probably incorrectly) stripped of it's `native` modifier. So clearly it's *calling* the `native`-stripped methods which is causing the problem.

What seems **really** odd is that the stack trace is only 16 frames deep; I'd have expected kinda more given that it was a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: +1, the first stack overflow question on Java/JNI that I didnot understand

Comment: Googling "asm native rewriting" brings up this question, which isn't a good sign!

Comment: Yeah, if Google had given me an answer, I wouldn't be here!

Comment: Stacktrace - stacktrace - stacktrace ...!!!

Comment: Are you giving the method a `Code` attribute? If not, I would suspect that ASM is getting confused because it's not being given sufficient information to write the file.

Comment: kdgregory, ASM doesn't care. But I can't reproduce the issue OP example aod java.lang.Object class. So, please post the stack trace.

Comment: I suspect as non-native methods need to have a body of code, the library doesn't like the fact the method doesn't have one.

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't be instrumenting away the native methods from java.lang.Object. If you're trying to modify non JRE classes, why not filter out the JRE classes and see if you still run into this problem?

Comment: I agree with Andy - doesn't the JVM do funny stuff when loading classes in the `java.` packages?

Comment: I don't want to filter out the JRE classes Because my goal of this is to kind of "sanitize" the JRE classes via the Instrumentation api. Yes, it does do funny stuff when loading the JRE classes, but so far (apart from this `native` thing) I haven't had any trouble going back and re-writing all of them after-the-fact

Comment: Maybe if you move the troublesome class out of the `java.` package, the additional validation the normal (non-bootstrap) classloader performs will tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's not quite as simple to replace native code with stubs but it's not far from that
- If you look at [ClassVisitor#visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions)](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) 
  you'll see that it returns a `MethodVisitor`
- [MethodVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) which you now have to make use of. If you want to make abstract stubs, you should add at least the call to `methodVisitor.visitEnd()`
- If you want to make empty stubs, you have to add `visitCode` and also return a value if necessary

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the accepted answer here is a fully working example of an instrumentation agent which uses ASM to replace the native method `java.net.NetworkInterface#getHardwareAddress()` with a stub that returns a fixed value.

```
public class MacModifyAgent {

    private static final String TARGET = "java/net/NetworkInterface";

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader l, String name, Class<?> c, ProtectionDomain d, byte[] b)
                    throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                if (TARGET.equals(name)) {
                    return instrument(b);
                }
                return b;
            }
        });
    }

    private static byte[] instrument(byte[] originalBytes) {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        ClassAdapter adapter = new ClassAdapter(cw);

        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalBytes);
        cr.accept(adapter, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }

    public static class ClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor implements Opcodes {
        public ClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
            super(ASM4, cv);
        }

        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature,
                String[] exceptions) {

            if ("getHardwareAddress".equals(name)) {
                MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access & ~ACC_NATIVE, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);

                MethodVisitor special = new StubReturnValue(mv, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
                return special;
            } else {
                return super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class StubReturnValue extends MethodVisitor implements Opcodes {
        private final MethodVisitor target;
        private byte[] mac;

        public StubReturnValue(MethodVisitor target, byte [] mac) {
            super(ASM4, null);
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitCode() {
            target.visitCode();
            target.visitVarInsn(BIPUSH, 6);
            target.visitIntInsn(NEWARRAY, T_BYTE);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                target.visitInsn(DUP);
                target.visitIntInsn(BIPUSH, i);
                target.visitIntInsn(BIPUSH, mac[i]);
                target.visitInsn(BASTORE);
            }

            target.visitInsn(ARETURN);
            target.visitEnd();
        }
    }
}
```