# Is there a way in Java to intercept the creation of a object by using Instrumentation?

Tags: java, exception, instrumentation

I need to intercept the creation of all ClassNotFoundException or NoClassDefError: the problem is that some of these exception are catched by some libraries and rethrowed in other exception type so I can't retrieve the class name.
Is there a way to do this in Java by using Intstrumentation?

Comment: This may be possible with ASM. I did something previously to change the behaviour of a built in java class - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706364/898289

Comment: Maybe something in that direction? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses%28java.lang.Class...%29

Comment: You can transform classes which create instances of these classes explicitly. But I doubt that you can intercept the creation of `NoClassDefError` instances by the JVM itself.

Comment: I've tried writing an Java Agent using java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer) with a System.out.println() logging all the classes. Somehow you ClassNotFoundException without the class being "seen" by the instrumentation. I think there must be something "special" about this class.

Comment: Yeah, there's special case.
`instrumentation.retransformClasses(ClassNotFoundException.class)` doesn't take any effect, despite other classes are able to be retransformed by the instrumentation

Comment: @Adam: could you post your code?

Comment: @Holger: if it is possible to intercept the constructor calling of these two exceptions it should be possible

Comment: Yes, but I have my doubts about the JVM calling the constructor when constructing the error internally.

Comment: “_these exception are catched by some libraries and rethrowed in other exception type_” are you sure those libraries are not setting the original exception as the cause of the new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) implementation and apply your logic in [`loadClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String,boolean)) or other available method. `ClassLoader` is the usual source of `ClassNotFoundException` in the application. Unless 3rd party libraries change the default class loading process (e.g. OSGI) they will still invoke your `ClassLoader`.

Comment: I need to intercept this exception for all runtime ClassLoaders

Comment: ClassLoaders are using delegation model, the child class loader calls the parent one if it can't load the class. You should be able to wrap the call to `super` with `try/catch` and spot the exception before re-throwing it.

Comment: If in the classpath there is a library that uses directly the parent class loader of mine classloader it will not works

Comment: @KarolDowbecki this only works if `loadClass` has been invoked on your custom class loader. Once you returned a class resolved via a `super` call, all of its dependencies will be resolved via the parent loader directly.

Answer (score 0):

The following example adds instrumentation to the constructor of `ClassNotFoundException` and does a `System.err.println` when it is invoked.

I'm unsure how to invoke a callback from the instrumentation which I assumed you'd need.

```
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.instrument.UnmodifiableClassException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassVisitor;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassWriter;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.MethodVisitor;
import net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.Opcodes;

public class ClassNotFoundExceptionIntercept {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws UnmodifiableClassException {
        inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader l, String name, Class<?> c, ProtectionDomain d, byte[] b)
                    throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                if ("java/lang/ClassNotFoundException".equals(name)) {
                    return instrument(b);
                }
                return b;
            }
        }, true);
        inst.retransformClasses(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.class);
    }

    private static byte[] instrument(byte[] originalBytes) {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        ClassAdapter adapter = new ClassAdapter(cw);
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(originalBytes);
        cr.accept(adapter, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }

    public static class ClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor implements Opcodes {
        public ClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
            super(ASM4, cv);
        }
        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature,
                String[] exceptions) {
            if ("<init>".equals(name)) {
                MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
                return new Wrapper(mv);
            } else {
                return super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Wrapper extends MethodVisitor {
        public Wrapper(MethodVisitor mv) {
            super(Opcodes.ASM4, mv);
        }
        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean itf) {
            mv.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);

            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn("Constructor invoked");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        }
    }

}
```

This needs compiling into a JAR file with a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: ClassNotFoundExceptionIntercept
Agent-Class: ClassNotFoundExceptionIntercept
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
```

and invoking with program argument `-javaagent:/home/adam/agent-example.jar`

This can be demonstrated to work with a test class that swallows the exception

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("brexit");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output

```
Constructor invoked
Constructor invoked
Constructor invoked
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: brexit
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it